# Video.js player doesn't work with Chakra-UI Modal component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, video.js, chakra-ui

I have a Next.JS app and I'm using Chakra-UI for components. I try to put a video.js player inside the modal but it does not work for some reason. I have the following code:

```
import {
    Box,
    useDisclosure,
    Modal,
    ModalOverlay,
    ModalContent,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalFooter,
    ModalBody,
    ModalCloseButton,
    Button
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";


export default function Video({ src, img, title }) {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

    /* Video player */
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    let player;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
            player = videojs(videoRef.current, {
                sources: [
                    {
                        src: "https://stream.mux.com/GJjLF93MGEmq4VfidIdZ4oMMAJRhEjSQ.m3u8",
                        type: "application/x-mpegURL"
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
        if (player) {
            player.on("pause", () => {
                console.log(player.currentTime(), "**********");
            });
        }
    });
    /** ------- **/

    return (
        <Box>
            <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                <ModalOverlay />
                <ModalContent>
                    <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalCloseButton />
                    <ModalBody>
                        <video controls ref={videoRef} className="video-js" />
                    </ModalBody>

                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button colorScheme='blue' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant='ghost'>Secondary Action</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

The video player works fine if I put it anywhere but inside the modal. In the Modal, it doesn't work. This is the result:
[image: video doesn't load]

How should I modify the Modal (based on [Chakra-UI](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/modal/usage)) so the video.js player works fine?